# runspider returns an empty file [DEBUG: Crawled (200)]

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

To analyze the prices of different products I have created a function that downloads them through the scrapy library, however, when I execute the routine returns an error message.

I have saved the scrapy.exe file in the same working directory where I run the .py file

this is my code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
class Articulo(Item):
    titulo = Field()
    precio = Field()
    descripcion = Field()
 
class MercadoLibreCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mercadoLibre'
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 5
    }
    download_delay = 1
 
    allowed_domains = ['articulo.mercadolibre.cl', 'listado.mercadolibre.cl']   #puedo poner más dominios solo poniendo comas
 
    start_urls = ['https://listado.mercadolibre.cl/animales-mascotas/caballos/']
 
    rules = (
        Rule(  # REGLA #1 => HORIZONTALIDAD POR PAGINACION
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'/_Desde_\d+'
            ), follow=True),
 
        Rule(   # REGLA #2 => VERTICALIDAD AL DETALLE PRODUCTOS
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'/MLC-'
            ), follow=True, callback='parse_items'),
    )
    
def limpiarTexto(self, texto): 
  nuevoTexto = texto.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('\t', ' ').strip()
  return nuevoTexto
 
def parse_items(self, response):
    item = ItemLoader(Articulo(), response)

    item.add_xpath('titulo', '//h1/text()')
    item.add_xpath('descripcion', '//div[@class="ui-pdp-description__content"]/p/text()', MapCompose(self. limpiarTexto))
    item.add_xpath('precio', '//span[@class="andes-money-amount__fraction"]/text()', MapCompose(self.limpiarTexto))

    yield item.load_item()
```

The code executed without problems, although as a result it returned an empty file. I think the problem lies in this "DEBUG: Crawled (200)+(referer: None)" message, but I don't quite understand how to fix it

```
    C:\Users\gusta\OneDrive\Documentos\Empresa>scrapy runspider 20220910_scraping_mercado_libre.py -o mercado_libre.csv -t csv
C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\__init__.py:131: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: The -t command line option is deprecated in favor of specifying the output format within the output URI. See the documentation of the -o and -O options for more information.
  feeds = feed_process_params_from_cli(
2022-09-11 02:55:48 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2022-09-11 02:55:48 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 2.0.1, Twisted 22.8.0, Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022), cryptography 37.0.4, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
2022-09-11 02:55:49 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 1,
 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True,
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
               '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36'}
2022-09-11 02:55:49 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-09-11 02:55:49 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 2f2010a00a1f6efa
2022-09-11 02:55:49 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-09-11 02:55:49 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-09-11 02:55:49 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-09-11 02:55:49 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-09-11 02:55:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-09-11 02:55:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-09-11 02:55:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-09-11 02:55:50 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 1646952198736 on C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-09-11 02:55:50 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 1646952198736 acquired on C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-09-11 02:55:50 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 1646952198736 on C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-09-11 02:55:50 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 1646952198736 released on C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-09-11 02:55:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://listado.mercadolibre.cl/animales-mascotas/caballos/> (referer: None)
2022-09-11 02:55:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (closespider_pagecount)
2022-09-11 02:55:51 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 332,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 105595,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.003421,
 'finish_reason': 'closespider_pagecount',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 11, 5, 55, 51, 184037),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 722794,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 52,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 52,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 11, 5, 55, 50, 180616)}
2022-09-11 02:55:51 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (closespider_pagecount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo in your rule here:

```
Rule(   # REGLA #2 => VERTICALIDAD AL DETALLE PRODUCTOS
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'/MCL-'
            ), follow=True, callback='parse_items')
```

It should be `MLC` (not **MCL**):

```
Rule(   # REGLA #2 => VERTICALIDAD AL DETALLE PRODUCTOS
                LinkExtractor(
                    allow=r'/MLC-'
                ), follow=True, callback='parse_items')
```

**UPDATE** After your fix you have another error in item processor. It should be:

```
item.add_xpath('descripcion', '//div[@class="ui-pdp-description__content"]/p/text()', MapCompose(self.limpiarTexto))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still doesn't work. I have edited it in the post

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still doesn't work. I've edited it again, based on your recommendation.

I also updated the error message.

Comment: What errors do you have? Everything works fine on my side.